# Обработка ошибок в node.js

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте. Допустим, есть задача взять инфу из базы, что-то с ней сделать, используя переданные пользователем данные (это что-то может вернуть ошибку), и отправить ее клиенту. Очень страшная реализация:

```
function sendToUser (cb) {
  db.get(selector, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      //???
      log(err);
      return cb(err);
    }
    doSomethingWithData(data, function (err, newData) {
      if (err) {
        //???
        log(err);
        return cb(err);
      }
      // что-то делаем
      cb(newData);
    })
  });
}

sendToUser(function render (err, finalData) {
  if (err) {
    res.writeHeader(???)
    res.render('/path/to/error/page', err);
  } else {
    res.render('/data', finalData);
  }
});
```

Как получить теперь http-код ошибки для отправки клиенту? Есть вариант писать что-то вроде

```
  db.get(selector, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      err.httpcode = 5xx;
      log(err);
      return cb(err);
    }
    doSomethingWithData(data, function (err, newData) {
      if (err) {
        err.httpcode = err.httpcode || 4xx; //Пользователь получит в ответе или "база данных не работает" или "неправильные данные в запросе".
```

, но это выглядит сильно просто и поэтому смущает)).
Как вы определяете http-код ошибки для отправки клиенту?

Comment: так если ошибка при коннекте, то откуда другая ? Отправляешь ошибку, и конец пакета. В чем проблема ? Не надо ничего запопинать, в response просто ставишь заголовок и потом `res.end('Error message');` или как там у вас реализовано.

Comment: если ошибки при коннекте сейчас не было, а потом будет. цепочка "обработок" (как это правильней назвать не знаю) может же обрываться на любом звене. вот в зависимости от звена, где что-то пошло не так, и будет свой код ошибки. но эту ошибку надо поднять по стеку. единственное что я придумал это записать в сам объект ошибки ее код и если надо будет какой-нибудь message.

Comment: в модели не надо заканчивать, ошибки модели обрабатывает контроллер. и общение модели с контроллером к http никакого отношения не имеет. типичный вызов модели выглядит так:

     model.method(params).then(successCallback,errorCallback); //зависит от вашей реализации promise, бывает .success(), .error()

Comment: Приложение на express. Организовал следующим образом:

    models
        ads
    routes
        get
    lib
        db
    app

Comment: В app все стандартно. Запускаем сервер, подключаем middleware и routes. В lib обертка над node-mongodb-native. В ads модуль, который манипулирует объявлениями (добавить, удалить, редактировать, найти в базе). ads использует db. После всех routes идет один обработчик исключений. Если до него доходит какая-нибудь ошибка, то он сам должен разобраться что с ней делать и что отправлять клиенту. Поэтому если в db, ads или в routes что-то произойдет, надо как-то сообщить этому единственному обработчику что собственно случилось.

Comment: ну сообщайте ему в виде массива, генерируйте что нить типа 

    error: [priority,code,message]

у него же есть объект response... но я вам говорю - это не mvc с виду, т.к. в mvc ошибки обрабатывает контроллер, тот кто обращается к модели. общий обработчик ошибок для меня выглядит странно как минимум. т.к. не всегда можно сказать что это за ошибка, не имея входных данных. К тому-же в обработке ошибок не столь важно сообщить об ошибке клиенту, как изменить поведение контроллера в зависимости от ошибки.

Comment: я имел ввиду что-то типа алгоритма 

    для всех [маша,петя,коля] {если есть пользователь в базе, добавить в выходнойМассив }

в таком случае если проверка наличия в базе кинет исключение, вам мало не покажется.

Comment: > поиск в модели, предполагающий not found, так что будете исключение бросать

В error напишу 404 и буду пробрасывать до обработчика.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо за все ответы. Дали пищу для размышлений. Походу не там завернул в процессе обучения)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как определяем ? Код ошибки это числовое представление одной из стандартных ошибок [определенных w3c](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), соответственно если запись не найдена - 404, если не авторизован то 401, если запрещено - 403 итд если упало что-то то 5xx ну а в заголовке это просто число, оно и не должно быть сложным его туда положить.

Comment: я сюда ответ положу, чтобы можно было дальше писать :) в общем да, подумайте над самой архитектурой обработки ошибок, по "стеку" вверх то положить не сложно, в конце концов сообщить обработчику об ошибке на любом уровне можно с помощью emit какого-нить. типа

    errorHandler.emit('error',errorParams)

и потом в конце, когда вроде как надо ответ формировать

   errorHandler.emit('end');

но это все направильно, очень запутает и какие-то простые действия будет сложно делать, я вам тоже посоветовал бы взять mvc фреймворк основанный на express, а не чистый express.

Comment: ну а если вас почему-то не устраивает набор ошибок http, вы всегда можете сделать свой протокол для общения с клиентом, генерируйте ответ в стиле {errors: [],data: {}} и пусть клиент сам думает, как на это реагировать. Но это тоже не очень нужно.

Comment: Стыдно признаться, но я забил на mvc. Я так понял, если я все правильно пойму (про mvc), этот вопрос сам собой отпадет?